# iPhone : Problem while capturing screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

I want to capture my screen view. My app is in Landscape. But while I try to capture the screen it capture view in portrait mode.

I want to make sure that screen capture is in landscape.

What should I do ?

Comment: can u plz explain with some code to understand your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use following one

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(480,320));
UIImage* result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I tried this but its not capturing my whole view. The screen which I am capturing is dynamic view.

Comment: give the size factor as per your view size.

Answer (score 0):

Compare the hight and width of the capture and rotate it if required.